# How to wait for 3 async functions to finish in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I am usng the following library to generate sha256 hashes:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-hash

The hashing is working but it is asynchronous. I am trying to figure out how to wait for the following code to execute:

```
async function hashAnswers() {
    try {
      await sha256(firstAnswer)
        .then(hash => { setFirstHash(hash)})
      await sha256(secondAnswer)
        .then(hash => { setSecondHash(hash)})
      await sha256(thirdAnswer)
        .then(hash => { setThirdHash(hash)})
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

and calling it here:

```
 async function handleSubmit() {
    await hashAnswers().then(result => {
      console.log(firstHash);
    })
  }
```

However, it does not wait for the answers to hash before logging.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps a way to bundle the three async queries?

Comment: [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT:

The solution proposed in the comments to use `Promise.all` is actually a good suggestion. You just need to have your `hashAnswers` function return a tuple of values which are hashes of the answers:

```
async function hashAnswers() {
    return Promise.all([
        sha256(firstAnswer), sha256(secondAnswer), sha256(thirdAnswer),
    ]).catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
       return [null, null, null];
    });
}
```

Now your `handleSubmit` function will have access to the values returned:

```
async function handleSubmit() {
    const [hash1, hash2, hash3] = await hashAnswers();
    setFirstHash(hash1);
    setSecondHash(hash2);
    setThirdHash(hash3);
    
    console.log(hash1);
}
```

---

#### Previous answer:

The first problem is that in react, `setState` is asynchronous and does not immediately update the state. So all your calls to `setXHash`, etc may not actually update the state before you are ready to use them.

The second problem is that your function will not have access to the updated values because they will be updated in a different render of the component which will be different from the current render in which the function was called. Remember that every state change causes the entire component to re-render.

Solution?

There are two potential solutions:

- Create another state which is updated when the function is finished
- Store the hashes in a mutable ref (`useRef`)

The second option may be the easiest to implement:

```
const firstHashRef = useRef();
// Do the same for secondHashRef, etc
...
async function hashAnswers() {
    try {
      await sha256(firstAnswer)
        .then(hash => { firstHashRef.current = hash; })
      await sha256(secondAnswer)
        .then(hash => { secondHashRef.current = hash; })
      await sha256(thirdAnswer)
        .then(hash => { thirdHashRef.current = hash; })
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Now in your `handleSubmit` function, you can `console.log(firstHashRef.current)` after the async `hashAnswers` is finished.

Comment: Good one. I wish he pointed out in his original post that all those `setFirstHash`, `setSecondHash` are actually state hooks, which in themselves are asynchronous.

Comment: I am running into the error "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'" in regards to the firstHashRef.current = hash etc

Comment: @kalculated if you are using typescript, then do this: `const firstHashRef = useRef<string>();`

Comment: @smac89 i like the promise solution better, so i went with that. one last thing, I am getting a "Type 'void' is not an array type." error for hash1, hash2, hash3 in handleSubmit. I am using typescript. is there a way around this?

Comment: @kalculated at the end of `hashAnswers` return an array with 3 null values: `return [null, null, null];`

Answer (score 1):

No need to `await` if you're using `then`. I'm not sure what `setFirstHash`, `setSecondHash` return, but it seem like `Promise.all` would probably do the job for you as suggested by Brian. Here is the gist:

```
const hashAnswers = () => {
    const promises = [];
        try {
            promises.push(
                sha256(firstAnswer).then(hash => {
                    setFirstHash(hash);
                    return 'first is set';
                })  
            );
            
            promises.push(
                sha256(secondAnswer).then(hash => {
                    setSecondHash(hash);
                    return 'second is set'
                })
            );
            /*
            ... More push() calls ...
             */
            
            return promises;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return [];
        }       
}

const handleSubmit = () => {
    Promise.all(hashAnswers())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        })
}
```

Note that in the event of an error, `hashAnswers` returns an empty array just so `Promise.all` can resolve, but you will see the error message via `console.log(error);`

Comment: setFirsthash etc are all state hooks! thanks will try this

Comment: In that case, you may want to return something arbitrary from those `then` functions as shown in the edited version.

Comment: Alright I changed the code - 

in handleSubmit, if I console.log(result), i get "first is set, second is set, third is set" 

but if i change it to console.log(firstHash), it still doesn't log the hashed answer

Comment: What's `firstHash`? I don't see that variable defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: the state hook "const [firstHash, setFirstHash] = useState('');"

Comment: If it's a state hook, then you should call it as a function, not as a reference. i.e. `console.log(firstHash());` and not `console.log(firstHash);`. But anyway, I think @smac89 has a better answer for you given your circumstances.