# Calling two async functions where the first one uses the state updated by the second in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating an app that gets data from a [Geoapify API](https://geoapify.com/), and I have three basic API functions that I have. The user has two options in the UI: to manually search through their cities or use their current location based on their IP.

I have multiple states that I use to store the data of coordinates, the city that the user either selected or is their current location, and the state with the same process.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [location, setLocation] = useState("")
const [city, setCity] = useState('')
const [state, setState] = useState('')
const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState("")
const [range, setRange] = useState(40225)
const [results, setResults] = useState([])
```

My first async function is `fetchCurrentLocation()`:

```js
async function fetchCurrentLocation() {
  await fetch("https://api.geoapify.com/v1/ipinfo?apiKey=API_KEY")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      setLocation(response);
      setCoordinates([response.location.latitude, response.location.longitude]);
      console.log(!coordinates ? coordinates : "");
      return response;
    });
}
```

For reference the JSON returned is in this format:

```json
{"country":{"name":"United States","iso_code":"US","name_native":"United States","phone_code":"1","capital":"Washington D.C.","currency":"USD,USN,USS","flag":"","languages":[{"iso_code":"en","name":"English","name_native":"English"}]},"state":{"name":"California"},"city":{"name":"Fremont"},"postcode":"94539","location":{"latitude":37.5497,"longitude":-121.9621},"continent":{"code":"NA","name":"North America"},"ip":"99.22.52.75"}
```

My second async function is `fetchCoordinates`, should someone manually select their location from the dropdown:

```js
async function fetchCoordinates() {
  setLocation({
    city: {
      name: city,
    },
    state: {
      name: state,
    },
  });
  await fetch(
    `https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?text=${city.concat(
      ", ",
      state
    )}&format=json&apiKey=API_KEY`
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      var res = response.results.filter((x) => x.result_type === "city");
      setCoordinates(!res[0].lat && !res[0].long ? "" : [res[0].lat, res[0].lon]);
      return res;
    });
}
```

For reference, the API returns the JSON in this format:

```json
{"results":[{"datasource":{"sourcename":"openstreetmap","attribution":"© OpenStreetMap contributors","license":"Open Database License","url":"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"},"old_name":"San José de Guadalupe","city":"San Jose","county":"Santa Clara County","state":"California","country":"United States","country_code":"us","lon":-121.890591,"lat":37.3361663,"state_code":"CA","formatted":"San Jose, CA, United States of America","address_line1":"San Jose, CA","address_line2":"United States of America","category":"administrative","result_type":"city","rank":{"importance":0.9374377648053739,"popularity":6.926723485149312,"confidence":1,"confidence_city_level":1,"match_type":"full_match"},"place_id":"512ac76471ff785ec0593842507f07ab4240f00101f9010fb6010000000000c00208","bbox":{"lon1":-122.045672,"lat1":37.124503,"lon2":-121.589153,"lat2":37.4692175}}]]}
```

I added the third async function to get the places based on the coordinates:

```js
async function getPlaces() {
  await fetch(
    `https://api.geoapify.com/v2/places?categories=office.charity,office.association,office.non_profit&filter=circle:${coordinates[1]},${coordinates[0]},5000&bias=proximity:${coordinates[1]},${coordinates[0]}&limit=20&apiKey=API_KEY`
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      setResults(response);
      console.log(results);
    });
}
```

There are two buttons, which process the async functions at different times:

```
<Button colorScheme='teal' size='lg' onClick={async () => await FinalSearch()}>Search</Button>
{/* another button */}
<Button colorScheme='green' size='lg' onClick={async () => await fetchCurrentLocation()}>Use Current Location</Button>
```

The function `FinalSearch` is as follows:

```js
async function FinalSearch() {
    return Promise.all([
      fetchCoordinates(), getPlaces()
    ]).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return [null, null, null]
    })
  }
```

For the button that has the text "Search", I tried to combine the two async functions into one by using this previous [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71848384/how-to-wait-for-3-async-functions-to-finish-in-react). However, it only updates when I click the button three times:

[image: Error message]

How can I get the async function to properly return the JSON in one call? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The problem is that this line `Promise.all([fetchCoordinates(), getPlaces()]);` that you have inside `FinalSearch` would resolve the two promises randomly, there isn't an order.

And even if there was an order, the updated state by `fetchCoordinates` would not have taken effect by the time `getPlaces` is called, as updating a state is an asynchronous task.

## Solution

One way to solve your problem is first to change `fetchCoordinates` so that it returns that array of `lat` and `log`, something like so:

```
async function fetchCoordinates() {
  setLocation({
    city: {
      name: city,
    },
    state: {
      name: state,
    },
  });
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?text=${city.concat(
      ", ",
      state
    )}&format=json&apiKey=API_KEY`
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  const filtredData = data.results.filter((x) => x.result_type === "city");
  setCoordinates(
    !filtredData[0].lat && !filtredData[0].long ? "" : [filtredData[0].lat, filtredData[0].lon]
  );
  return [filtredData[0].lat, filtredData[0].lon];
}
```

Change `getPlaces` so that it takes `lat`, and `log` as parameter:

```
async function getPlaces(lat, long) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.geoapify.com/v2/places?categories=office.charity,office.association,office.non_profit&filter=circle:${long},${lat},5000&bias=proximity:${long},${lat}&limit=20&apiKey=API_KEY`
  );
  const data = res.json();
  setResults(data);
}
```

Change `FinalSearch` so that it gives the coordinates returned by `fetchCoordinates` to `getPlaces`.

```
async function FinalSearch() {
  try {
    const cordinates = await fetchCoordinates();
    getPlaces(...cordinates);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(err);
    return [null, null, null];
  }
}
```

Comment: So the general principle here would be, don't put data in state if you don't have to?